# WCF SOAP service returns Not Found for a large request and works OK for a smaller one

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ssl, soap, https

I have a SilverLight application that calls WCF service by POST via SSL and sends large request. Everything works OK on a local machine with a self-signed certificate. Moreover, it works on a remote server but only for a small request. When the application make a POST request (using SOAP) for a big scope of data I get a CommunicationException: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." The same use case on the local machine with absolutely the same web.config file (except of the sql connection string) works without the issue. It seems that the problem in the IIS configuration. I tried to investigate IIS logs but did not find any information about the requests as something before the logging kernel rejected the request. I have read a lot of articles where people propose different settings of the endpoints bindings, tried them but have not achieved success. 
My configuration of the services is the next:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
    <!--...(other settings) -->
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer> 

<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <!--... (other services)-->
        <service name="SD.Web.Services.ClientUser.UserLayersService">
            <endpoint address="soap" 
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      contract="SD.Web.Services.ClientUser.IUserLayersService" />

            <endpoint address="json" 
                      behaviorConfiguration="SD.Web.Services.AspNetAjaxBehavior" 
                      binding="webHttpBinding" 
                      contract="SD.Web.Services.ClientUser.IUserLayersService" />

            <endpoint address="mex" 
                      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                     maxBufferSize="2097152"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2097152">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                     maxBufferSize="2097152"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2097152">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SD.Web.Services.AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp  defaultBodyStyle="Bare" 
                    defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" 
                    automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" 
                    faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using Fiddler 4. Reader quotas have to be set.

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                 maxBufferSize="2097152"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2097152">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                 maxBufferSize="2097152"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2097152">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```